# Avoid Scientific notation in cut function in R

Tags: r, cut, scientific-notation

How to avoid scientific notation present in the Intervals created by the cut function.

```
a<-seq(10000,50000, by=500 )
cut(a, breaks = seq(0,max(a)+300, by = 300))
```

I have tried the below but it doesn't help.

```
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)
```

Comment: Try with adding the argument `dig.lab = 5`.

Comment: You can thank the help file `?cut`.

Comment: The `cut()` function cheerfully ignores `options('scipen'), options('digits')` etc. (It's also off-by-2 in the way it handles its own `dig.lab` parameter)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

*As suggested by Pascal,*

Try with adding the argument **dig.lab = 5** to cut function.